# XSLT comparing values from different branches of XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, compare

I need help with XSLT... In the input xml, I have:

```
<shop>
  <categories>
    <category categoryId="63" parentCategoryId="239">
      <name>Fruit</name>
    </category>
    <category categoryId="62" parentCategoryId="239">
      <name>Vegetable</name>
    </category>
    <category categoryId="60" parentCategoryId="221">
      <name>Furniture</name>
    </category>
    ...
  <categories>
  <products>
    <product productId="3" productCode="1.05">
      <name>Chair</name>
      <categories>
        <category>60</category>
      </categories>
    </product>
    <product productId="21" productCode="1.59">
      <name>Apple</name>
      <categories>
        <category>63</category>
      </categories>
    </product>
    ...
  </products>
</shop>
```

I need to create list of products, where I have name of product and name of its category. How can I do that? This don't work for me...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="shop">
    <export>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="products" />
    </export>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:for-each select="product">
      <polozka>
        <product_name>
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </product_name>
        <xsl:for-each select="/shop/categories/category">
          <xsl:if test="boolean(@categoryId = /shop/products/product/categories/category)">
            <category_name>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </category_name>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </polozka>    
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd be glad if there is anybody who can help me...

Comment: Can you add a sample of what you expect your output too look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look up a **category** based on its **@categoryId** then consider using a key to do the looking up

```
<xsl:key name="category" match="category" use="@categoryId"/>
```

Then, assuming each **Product** belongs to only one category, you can simply look up the name of category for a product like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('category', categories/category)/name"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="category" match="category" use="@categoryId"/>

   <xsl:template match="shop">
      <export>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="products"/>
      </export>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="products">
      <xsl:for-each select="product">
         <polozka>
            <product_name>
               <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </product_name>
            <category_name>
               <xsl:value-of select="key('category', categories/category)/name"/>
            </category_name>
         </polozka>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If a **Product** element could have multiple characters, then you would need to use a **for-each** loop instead

```
 <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
     <category_name>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('category', .)/name"/>
     </category_name>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the @CategoryId of each category to all the products:

```
@categoryId = /shop/products/product/categories/category
```

which will always be true, since each product is related to an existing category.

You have to compare it to the category of the *current* product. You don't need a `<xsl:if>` for that. It can be done with a predicate. Replace your for-each with this one:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/shop/categories/category[@categoryId = current()/categories/category]">
     <category_name>
         <xsl:value-of select="name" />
     </category_name>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now it should filter out the categories that don't match the categories of the current product.